# .edmx file cannot update the model, not able to select the tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am opening the WebStoreDBModel.edmx file.  Inside of the file I right click Update Model from Database.  There I am in the ADD tab, but I cannot select the TABLES or anything else (Views or Stored Procedures and Functions).  I have a dababase with 3 tables connected together (Category, Cart, Product).  Can someone explain me why I am not able to regenerate the model ?   I need to regenerate because When I am trying to Add a new Controller it display No Model Classses are available.  Please check that the project has been compiled.    I did  DEBUG / BUILD my project.   Any idea ?

Comment: did you add a new table ?

Comment: @Shyju  No I added nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't created any new objects( tables/functions etc..) since you created the EDMX file for the last time,then "Add" tab won't allow you to select anything. You need to use the "**Refresh**" tab.

If you added a new column to the existing table/updated a column in an existing table, You should use the "**Refresh**" tab.

[image]

Comment: What I should do in the refresh tab ?

Comment: @user3127986 You can select here and you have the "FINISH" button. Click that and it will update your edmx

Comment: When I get in the Refresh tab, I see all my 4 tables but no box to select it.  Are you saying I should just do finish because I cannot select the NEXT tab (it is grey out)  So I add a dummy column and then remove it later ?

Comment: I went to the refresh (didn't select anything) click finish but when I go to the add Controller I still have the same error

Comment: you can select the the table by clicking on it.(no checkboxes) You can expand the "tables" to see the available tables. Select it and click finish. Now close the edmx file and open it again and see whether your changes are available there.

Comment: I selected 1 by 1 every 4 table (1 at a time) in the refresh and did finish.  The Controller always complain about No Model Classes are available please check that the project has been compiled.

Comment: That is y i asked you to first check your EDMX file to see whether changes has been available there. close the open files and re-open it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48999/discussion-between-user3127986-and-shyju)

Comment: You cannot select anything in the refresh or delete tab, it is read only you can only select tables/views in the add tab.